# how to show bounding box in the Viewport Solid Mode for items added via geometry node collection

Tags: 3d-view, geometry-nodes, geometry

In my Viewport Solid Mode, I want to view items i'm adding to a plane via a collection as bounding box, but still view my terrain as "solid"

I have a plane that i'm creating a terrain via noise texture... then i'm adding a collection of items as "instance on Points"...  but my computer is too slow, so I would like to see the items as bounding box.

If I go to "object properties" and change the viewport display to "bounding", it changes it for the individual items, but **NOT** for the ones added via the geometry node.

[image]

[image]

[image]

link to blend file:
https://filedropper.com/d/s/7IYvbKPqWqMuAH2RHgfoPDXoDwYZ41

Comment: did you try to add bounding box node between collection and instance node?

Comment: Somehow I cannot reproduce the behavior. When I switch the object containing the geometry node from *Solid* to *Bounds*, everything is displayed as a bounding box. The grid, the objects instantiated, everything, if I switch only the object in the collection to *Bounds*, only that is displayed as a bounding box. Can you share with us your blend file?

Comment: @quellenform  I've added a link to the blend file with filedropper hope it works

Comment: @Chris the bounding box node after the collection seems to do the trick. thanks

Comment: @Chris  but then it's annoying, I have to remove the bounding node and add it every time I want to render. I can't have it affect only the viewport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the node `Set Shade Smooth`!

For some reason I don't know, it overrides the setting for *Viewport Display*.

If you just apply the node to the objects that are actually created in your geometry nodes, then it works.

[image]